# Semantic UI : Tabular Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am working with [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) and I am having trouble with their [Tabs](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/). The first tab is showing as the active tab, but when you click on the second tab, the tab does not change. You can see their example under "Attached" [here](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html). You can see my example below. I believe it is set up correctly. I also set up this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxrbaldwin/zu4kG/) with Semantic and jQuery included. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
    <a class="active item">One</a>
    <a class="item">Two</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
    <h4>Product Name</h4>
    <p>Here is the description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript to wire the tabs.

I've modified your fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabular.menu .item').tab({history:false});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zu4kG/5/

Also refer to this blog post: http://patrickgawron.com/wp/semantic-ui/

Please note that I've added jquery.address.js as well

Comment: This is definitely a solution to this issue, but what I found is that there are many different solutions to this problem. I was wondering if I was missing something that would make Semantic take this action automatically, but it looks like they are trying to give you the flexibility to create your own action.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I think you are misunderstanding the word semantic. It doesn't mean no JavaScript, it means that the HTML is not misused, compared to how it was intended and that it contains (additional) information that is computer usable.

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah I get what you mean. There are some javascript functions that are included in the semantic.js file. I did not know if I was missing a selector that could have been included in that file.

Answer (score 3):

The issue that I was hoping to solve was that I thought that I was missing something that would trigger an action built into Semantic. It looks like Semantic just wants to give the developer the flexibility to create their own actions on these tabs. They do that by providing the structure and some possible transitions for your actions. Essentially, there are many different solutions to how this action can function. Below I have provided a very simple solution using Semantic's classes and jQuery. Here is the [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/maxrbaldwin/zu4kG/7/)

```
$('.item').click(function(){
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: A small improvement :-) 

$(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue and this answer helped to point the right direction. My problem was at the end that the first tab was not visible right from the beginning, so you needed to click at least one tab.

```
<div class="ui bottom attached active tab segment" data-tab="first">
    <h4>Product Name</h4>
    <p>Here is the description</p>
</div>
```

Adding the "active" class to the tab content HTML structure fixed this.

Comment: This is the best answer for me, this is the information they missed in their own documentation !!

Comment: Love this answer. That explain the issue I had. Thanks.

Comment: In our case the tabs were activated with `.tab()` before the visibility condition was resolved.